# How do I pause/stop a song that's being played?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I have created a program where I can play a song, However I cannot get it to pause/stop and when I click the play button again the song loops over and over again. How can i get the song to pause or stop?

Here's my source code below to play a song:

```
public void sound(String nm) {   
    AudioStream BGM; //Backround Music

    try {
        InputStream test = new FileInputStream("./"+nm+".wav");
        BGM = new AudioStream(test);

        AudioPlayer.player.start(BGM);

    }
    catch (IOException error) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: What play button? There are no UI elements in your code.

Comment: I would read the documentation of the class of `AudioPlayer.player`. We don't know what class it is, so we can't help.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  From past experience, I guess `AudioPlayer` is in the `sun.com` packages?  They are undocumented, cannot be relied upon to be in a non-Oracle JRE, or even the next version of the Oracle JRE.  **Don't use them.**  Instead use the Java Sound based [`Clip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html) to play short sounds.  See the [info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for a short example.  Check the Java Docs for `Clip` (linked earlier in comment) for how to stop one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using [this example](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077521/learn-java/java-tip-24--how-to-play-audio-in-applications.html), which is using sun.audio.* namespace.

As you can see from the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/audio/AudioPlayer.java), if you want to stop, you can use `AudioPlayer.player.stop(BGM);` with the same reference as a parameter that you used for play.

Answer (score 0):

Your answere is maybe in the AudioPlayer class.
take a look in it- perhaps there is also a pause() and stop () function.